# Ruby's ternary operator

Tags: ruby

I understand that this code

```
options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
```

translates to

```
if arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash)
    options = arguments.pop
else
    options = {}
end
```

When I try

```
10 > 5 ? puts "greater" : puts "less"
```

I get an error. However

```
puts 10 > 5 ? "greater" : "less"
```

returns `"greater"` What is the difference between the two codes?

Comment: When posting questions that concern exceptions raised by your code, please give the complete error message and, if it's not obvious, the line that raised it.  Error messages contain valuable information; you need to study them carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a syntax error and a matter of precedence of keywords/operators. The `?` of the ternary operator has higher precedence than the argument passing to `puts`, and therefore ruby parses

```
10 > 5 ? puts "greater" : puts "less"
```

as

```
(10 > 5) ? (puts) ("greater")
```

which is invalid syntax, as `:` would be expected after `puts`.

```
10 > 5 ? puts("greater") : puts("less")
```

would work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a syntax error (my IRB says `syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('`). This will work as your expect it to:

```
10 > 5 ? (puts "greater") : (puts "less")
```

Answer (score -2):

With Ternary Operators you are putting your action first in the first example you are doing `options =` which is correct. In your second example you are putting the `puts` after checking if `10 > 5`. Its basically just a syntax error.